# Alter results programmatically

Tags: importing-exporting, views

I'm using views data export module to output results as csv, xls, xml and txt files

I'm using  Batched export (with Segment size 100) because there are many results.

I have some fields which I want to alter their values.

I have implemented [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) to replace field values with ones I'm getting from webservice.

The problem that some values are correctly changed, others not

Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a pre-render function, I think the correct spot to modify values is actually [hook_views_post_execute()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_post_execute/7).  This is invoked after the query has run, but before the data has been passed to rendering.

> Adding output to the view can be accomplished by placing text on $view->attachment_before and $view->attachment_after. Altering the content can be achieved by editing the items of $view->result.

It has been a while since I've personally played with Views Data Export so I'm not 100% sure why you're seeing only some values change and not others, but I recall the rendering of the export being a little abnormal compared to the usual render process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried hook_views_post_execute() but it doesn't take effect, none of the values are replaced :(

Comment: Shoot...

I think someone will need to see a code snippet (preferably the pre_render you've implemented) to see exactly what you're  attempting to do to figure out why it isn't working.